# Does jQuery have built in JSON support?

Tags: jquery, json

Does jQuery have built in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) support or must I use a plugin like jquery.json-1.3.min.js ?

Comment: I don't see how this is programming related?

Comment: @geejay you don't?  jquery is javascript, AJAX, json, all those are very programming related I think.

Comment: @geejay - a yes/no programming question should be community wiki? C'mon!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use $.ajax and set the [dataType option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) to "json":

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: ({id : this.getAttribute('id')}),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(json){
         alert(json.foo);
      }
   }
);
```

Also, [$.get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) and [$.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype) have an optional fourth parameter that allows you to set the data type of the response, e.g.:

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    $.post(url, data, callback, "json");
};

$.getJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    $.get(url, data, callback, "json");
};
```

Comment: this is the way I am trying to do it actually, I am getting a json response from an ajax call so this is perfect for my situation!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, absolutely it does.  You can do something like:

```
$.getJSON('/foo/bar/json-returning-script.php', function(data) {
    // data is the JSON object returned from the script.
});
```

Comment: thanks this is good to know, in my situation karim79's response is the way I need to do it though.  +1 I wonder why they have a plugin for json if it is built in!?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's JSON support is simplistic, throwing caution to the wind.  I've used `$.ajax` and then parse the response text with the [json.org javascript library](http://www.json.org/js.html).  It lexically parses to avoid using `eval()` and possibly executing arbitrary code.

Comment: the reccomended json2.js from json.org actually does use eval. It just has some complicated sanitization code run through the json source first. There's a lexical parser as fallback, but it runs much slower, by all accounts.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery supports *decoding* JSON, but does not support *encoding* out-of-the-box.  For encoding, you'll need a plugin, a separate library, or a browser that supports the JSON.stringify and JSON.parse commands natively.